# Métodos para testar aplicação Spring não são encontrados

Tags: java, spring, junit

Estou acompanhando o seguinte artigo: [Introduction To Spring MVC Test Framework](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-mvc-test-framework/)

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/product/1"))
.andExpect(status().isOk().
.alwaysExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")));
```

E a classe tem estas anotações:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:/spring/spring*.xml")
```

Contudo não esta encontrando os métodos `get()`, `status()` e `content()`, de onde esses métodos são importados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente trocar as importações para estas, nesta ordem:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

e corrija após o isOk()

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/product/1"))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.alwaysExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, funcionou aqui +1